# Рендер текстуры с заданной прозрачностью

Tags: c++, c, directx

Windows XP, DirectX9

Текстура с альфаканалом выводится правильно после настройки:

```
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
```

Теперь требуется выводить текстуру с 50% прозрачностью (помимо собственного альфаканала текстуры).

Сейчас решается путем предварительной обработки текстуры в фотошопе, но в дальнейшем может потребоваться большое кол-во вариантов прозрачности.

Каким образом можно совмещать значение альфа канала текстуры с дополнительным, заданным значением при рендере. Можно ли обойтись без шейдеров?

Comment: Возможно не в тему, но в OpenGL есть режимы сложения текстуры с материалом - сложение, умножение. Посмотрите на эту тему в D3D.

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, то значение альфа-канала можно задавать в материале. Ну, и, соответственно, уровень прозрачности там же. Только нужно правильно выставить настройки рендера:

```
// В качестве источника альфа-компоненты используем
// параметры материала
Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
```